# Return product description

Tags: php

I have a function that I want to return product description, but in this moment it returns the category description of each product. What can be wrong? Thanks in advance for your time, I really appreciate if you can tell me what is wrong.

```
protected function GetDescription($ProductID)
{
    $terms = get_the_terms( $ProductID, 'product_cat' );    

    foreach ((array) $terms as $term) {
        $product_description = $term->description;
        break;
    }


    return $product_description;
}
```

Where is called the function:

```
foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            $ProductID = $post_id;

            $OkaziiConnectorProduct = new Okazii_Connector_Product();
            
            $OkaziiConnectorProduct->ID = $ProductID;
            $OkaziiConnectorProduct->UniqueID = $this->GetUniqueID($ProductID);
            $OkaziiConnectorProduct->Title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title($ProductID));
            $OkaziiConnectorProduct->Category = $this->GetCategory($ProductID);
            $OkaziiConnectorProduct->Description = $this->GetDescription($ProductID);
}
```

Comment: Where and how to you use this protected method? because from your code this methods accepts a product id, gets all product terms, loops only once, because of the break (this will always return the first term description, so if you have multiple terms for a product take that into account), then it returns the product description variable (if no terms were found this will create a php warning because the variable was never set, consider creating the variable outside the loop with empty string as value);

Comment: Thanks for your comment, here is `foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    $ProductID = $post_id;

    $OkaziiConnectorProduct = new Okazii_Connector_Product();
    
    $OkaziiConnectorProduct->ID = $ProductID;
    $OkaziiConnectorProduct->UniqueID = $this->GetUniqueID($ProductID);
    $OkaziiConnectorProduct->Title = html_entity_decode(get_the_title($ProductID));
    $OkaziiConnectorProduct->Category = $this->GetCategory($ProductID);
    $OkaziiConnectorProduct->Description = $this->GetDescription($ProductID);`

Comment: I did, thank you!

Comment: Not sure how you can call this protected method outside of the class itself, should be public (maybe the class extends/implements anothe class, so in that case its correct). You use this logic inside a foreach loop, it will loop all `$post_ids` and return the relevant description for that post id, so if you have more than one value inside `$post_ids` it does what expected, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is not my script, I wanted to make this script to display product description into a xml and I made that function, but I haven't experience with php. So... I hope that is a person can help me to modify that function to get product description, not category description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the product description instead of product terms descriptions you can do this.

```php
protected function GetDescription ($ProductID) {
    return get_post_field('post_content', $ProductID);
}
```

This will return the content field by the id, if no content exists it will return an empty string.